# Unable to get a synchronous result with Parse Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, callback, promise

I want to save a new user in Parse.com along with a geopoint.  I had it working somehow though it seems to work inconsistently at best upon further testing.  Here is the code I have, most of the time, console.log shows that geoPoint is undefined and it does not save the geoPoint. var geo relates to a Parse Class that contains zip code based geoPoints, btw.

```
$scope.merchantSignUp = function () {

    var user = new Parse.User();

    var uZip = $scope.user.zip;
    var geo = Parse.Object.extend("Geography");
    var geoQuery = new Parse.Query(geo);
    geoQuery.equalTo("zip", uZip);
    geoQuery.select(["latitude", "longitude"]);
    geoQuery.first({
        success: function (geoPoint) {
            console.log(geoPoint); //undefined
            var x = geoPoint.get("latitude");
            var y = geoPoint.get("longitude");
            //console.log(x);
            //console.log(y);
            var point = new Parse.GeoPoint({
                latitude: x,
                longitude: y
            });

            user.set("username", $scope.user.email);
            user.set("password", $scope.user.password);
            user.set("zip", $scope.user.zip);
            user.set("location", point);
            user.signUp(null, {
                success: function (user) {
                    // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
                    console.log("signup worked")
                },
                error: function (user, error) {
                    // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
                    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message); //I JUST KNOCKED THIS OUT FOR TESTING!!!
                }
            })


        }
    })
}
```

The function is called from Angular HTML passing in all $scope variables.

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: No, promises don't give you synchronous results. Instead they just are a way to represent asynchronous result, in a much more comfortable way than callbacks.